# Change table of contents title in Org mode according to document language for beamer export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm exporting a `*.org` file to `pdf` using `LaTeX` as a `beamer` presentation. I want to change the title of the TOC slide to Spanish.

I've tried the solutions described in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/21239/16602), but they don't work for me.  In one of the answers there is even a comment saying that the solutions don't work for `beamer`.

Is there any way to accomplish this without manually editing the `*.tex` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ox-beamer.el` seems to be deficient in the multilanguage department. If you are talking about the slide that's entitled `Outline`, try customizing the
variable `org-beamer-outline-frame-title`.

Comment: That's it! Adding `'(org-beamer-outline-frame-title "Customized Title")` to the `custom-set-variables` works.