# How can i make org mode export latex file with a custom language?

Tags: org-export, latex

I need romanian for my school reports, i want to write them in org mode.

Is there some `#+LANG` attribute? Do i need to set some emacs variables? I'd really like a per-file solution more

Comment: See [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21239/change-table-of-contents-title-in-org-mode-according-to-document-language). The dictionary is not completed for some languages, you may need to patch it.

Comment: It sets the pdflang attribute but doesn't change the date format or table of contents...

Comment: Yes, that's the missing part I mentioned... You have two choices: 1. Patch it locally in your configuration 2. Send a patch to Org mode.

Comment: Oh, it's fixed now... I added `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[romanian]babel` and it seems to work now. even better, the `#+LANGUAGE` attribute regardless of what version the babel package is. nice

Comment: Alright, so just using babel makes `#+LANGUAGE` work. Thanks, @FirminMartin

Comment: Nice! I estimated that romanian would have the same issue than CJK languages. They have to rely on the dictionary and other LaTeX settings.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the following code to make `#+LANGUAGE` work:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[romanian]{babel}
#+LANGUAGE: ro
```

I don't know why, but removing the `[romanian]` breaks it. It can be any language because the only thing that matters is the `#+LANGUAGE` value now.

Comment: `#+language:` isn't used properly, for whatever I define as propely in `\LaTeX{}`, but is used when generation HTML `C-c C-e h h`.
You need to add the language to `#+class_options: [a4paper,romanian]` or as you do, as an optional argument to package `\usepackage[romanian]{babel}`.
You should probably also set `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[AUTO]{inputenc}`.  At least that worked for me and `swedish` and `#+language: sv`.