# How to change the "Figure" text created when exporting a LaTeX file with org-mode. I want it to say "Figura" as I speak Spanish

Tags: org-mode, latex, translation

When I export all the images get the "figure" and the number of the image with the caption. When I export I want it to say "figura" instead of the English word.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, all you have to do is add a header:

```
#+LANGUAGE: es
```

Don't forget to either close and reopen the file, or do `C-c C-c` on the header so that the setup will be refreshed.

That seems to work e.g. for text and HTML export, but LaTeX export does not work for me: it seems to require additional setup that I have not figured out yet.

EDIT: just to close the loop, for LaTeX, Org mode requires some help. First, the relevant LaTeX babel language package needs to be installed. This varies with the distro - on my Fedora 33 system, I had to
do:

```
sudo dnf install texlive-babel-spanish
```

Then the header had to be augmented:

```
#+LANGUAGE: es
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[AUTO]{babel}

...
```

Not sure why the latex exporter does not do that automatically.

Comment: It didn't change in the LaTeX file, but as you said, it did work with the HTML export. I wonder what's missing :(.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: I found the answer here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21239/change-table-of-contents-title-in-org-mode-according-to-document-language